# Dropdown Item & Hamburger not collapsing/not working even if they resize well

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, dropdown, hamburger-menu

I'm currently starting to learn web development with *Bootstrap*, and I'm currently stuck with the navbars, specifically with the dropdown/collapse feature which doesn't seem to be working with dropdown item & hamburger icon.

I've already tried to load the most recent scripts (found in BS webpage), which in some other posts seems to have worked, but not for me unfortunately...

Find below my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Web Test #2</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- body code goes here -->
    <div id="myNavbar" >
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light navbar-light sticky-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Web App </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">   
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Home </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> About </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Products </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toogle="dropdown"> Contact us </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Facebook </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Instagram</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> e-mail</a>

            </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <form class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
<!-----Colapsible button here -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toogle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>           

    <!------end---> 

    </nav>  


    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

These are the scripts used, in the following order:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: data-toogle="dropdown" should be data-toggle="dropdown" for sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this example. I have taken an example from bootstrap like you ([Bootstrap-Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/)) and have changed the attributes like you.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- just the navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Web App</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Contact us
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Facebook</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Instagram</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">E-Mail</a>

        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The *hamburger* item works here, but in your example you have the search-field and search-button outside of the navbar-collapse. Is this on purpose and you don't want to collapse the search-field? In my example the search-field will collapse too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It now works, also noticed in another comment that the collapse had a typo :) thanks a lot!!